# Bootstrap's modal - click on cancel button - trigger `close()` or `dismiss()`?

Tags: javascript, angular-ui-bootstrap

[Bootstrap's modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) provides two methods to hide the dialog:

> close(result) (Type: function) - Can be used to close a modal, passing
>   a result.
>
> dismiss(reason) (Type: function) - Can be used to dismiss a modal,
>   passing a reason.

Is my understanding correct that I should use `close` when a user clicks on the `OK` button on the dialog, and `dismiss` when the user clicks on the `cancel` button?

Comment: yes.  the reason for your confusion is that you're under the impression that the only two options can be `OK` and `Cancel` whereas bootstrap is trying to provide you with the code you'd need to create any set of buttons you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the case where you have 'Yes', 'No', and 'Cancel'

eg. Preparing to connect to a chatroom, you might ask the user if they want to use their usual nickname, Yes would result in a connection with their nickname, No would result in a connection with a Guest nickname, and Cancel would result in no connection (dismissed)

**Cancel is dismissed, yes and no are closed (with a further result)**

Of course, there could be many more button combinations, but Yes/No/Cancel is quite common.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessary.
A reason can be self-explaintory, like close a modal due a click on a link inside the modal or an event that does not pass between standard "ok || cancel"

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `result` would indicate that closing is the way to "properly" close a modal, which resolves the `result` promise.

- `result` (Type: `promise`) - Is resolved when a modal is closed and rejected when a modal is dismissed.`

Judging by that, I would say that you are correct in your assumption.